# multiple inheritance with concept-based polymorphism c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Using [concept-based polymorphism](http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2016-10-10-runtime-polymorphism/2016-10-10-runtime-polymorphism.pdf) by that focuses on using value semantics and type erasure to implement type polymorphism, how would one implement multiple inheritance?

An example of the interface would look as follows. It defines a type, serializable, to require the functions serialize and size with the appropriate signature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Serializable {
public:
  template <typename T>
  Serializable(T x) : self_(new model<T>(move(x)))
  { }

  friend size_t serialize(const Serializable& x, uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize) {
    x.self_->serialize_(buffer, bufferSize);
  }
  friend size_t size(const Serializable& x) {
    x.self_->size_();
  }

private:
  struct Concept {
    virtual ~Concept() = default;
    virtual size_t serialize_(uint8_t*, size_t bufferSize) const = 0;
    virtual size_t size_() const = 0;
  };
  template <typename T>
  struct model : Concept {
    model(T x) : data_(move(x)) { }
    size_t serialize_(uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize) const
    { serialize(data_, buffer, bufferSize); }
    size_t size_() const
    { size(data_); }

    T data_;

  };

  shared_ptr<const Concept> self_;
};
```

A class that then implements the interface is shown below. Instead of directly inheriting the pure virtual functions, it uses the same function names. MyClassB later used and is an identical implementation, only with a different name.

```
class MyClassA {
public:
  MyClassA(const string& name) :
    name_(name)
  { }

  friend size_t serialize(const MyClassA& x, uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize);
  friend size_t size(const MyClassA& x);
private:
  const string name_;
};

size_t serialize(const MyClassA& x, uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize) {
  size_t bytesToWrite = size(x);
  if(bytesToWrite <= bufferSize) {
      memcpy(buffer, x.name_.c_str(), bytesToWrite);
    } else {
      bytesToWrite = 0;
    }
  return bytesToWrite;
}

size_t size(const MyClassA& x) {
  x.name_.length();
}
```

In addition, the same signature is created for a vector.

```
size_t size(const vector<Serializable>& x) {
  size_t totalSize = 0;
  for (auto& e : x) {
    totalSize += size(e);
  }
  return totalSize;
}

size_t serialize(const vector<Serializable>& x, uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize) {
  size_t bytesToWrite = size(x);
  size_t offset = 0;
  if(bytesToWrite <= bufferSize) {
      for (auto& e : x) {
        offset += serialize(e, buffer + offset, bufferSize - offset);
      }
    } else {
      bytesToWrite = 0;
    }
  return bytesToWrite;
}
```

To then use the type, MyClassA, MyClassB and the vector, the client-side code below creates the objects, adds them to a vector and then prints them.

```
int main() {
  vector<Serializable> channel;
  uint8_t buffer[30] = {};

  MyClassA myClassA("Hello World!");
  serialize(myClassA, buffer, sizeof buffer);
  cout << buffer << endl;

  cout << "-------------------" << endl;

  channel.emplace_back(MyClassA(" Apples"));
  channel.emplace_back(MyClassB(" Oranges"));
  serialize(channel, buffer, sizeof buffer);
  cout << buffer << endl;

  cout << "-------------------" << endl;

  cout << size(channel) << endl;

  cout << "-------------------" << endl;

  vector<Serializable> channel2;
  channel2.emplace_back(channel);
  channel2.emplace_back(channel);
  serialize(channel2, buffer, sizeof buffer);
  cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

The code has been prepared in the following repository. To build run scons in the root directory: https://github.com/moritz89/type-erasure-test?files=1

Back to the original question, would it be possible to create additional interfaces, e.g., ReportError or Client, that define functions that have to be implemented and can be unified to create multiple inheritance structures?

Comment: IMHO you should implement it in code using those squigly lines and stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Re: "would it be possible to create additional interfaces, e.g., ReportError or Client, that define functions that have to be implemented and can be unified to create multiple inheritance structures?" I don't see why not. What have you tried?

Comment: Added code to show the type of polymorphism I am talking about.

Comment: @AndyG I'll write up the code and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you do need to change your approach a bit so we don't end up needlessly duplicating. First, we need a simple `empty_model` class:

```
template <typename T, typename ... <class> Models>
struct empty_model : Models<empty_model> {
  model(T x) : data_(move(x)) { }
  T data_;
};
```

This only has whatever code is necessary to build a proxy for a `T`. Next, we have to turn our per-concept models into things that *only* handle forwarding the interface, but not ownership, via CRTP:

```
  // Still nested in serializable, or whatever concept
  template <typename D>
  struct model : Concept {
    size_t serialize_(uint8_t* buffer, size_t bufferSize) const
    { serialize(static_cast<const D&>(*this).data_, buffer, bufferSize); }
    size_t size_() const
    { size(static_cast<const D&>(*this).data_); }
  };
```

So, for each concept, we are writing the nested `model` class a bit different, but so far the amount of boiler plate is not any larger. We now use typedefs to create actual models that we want:

```
template <class T>
using serializable_model  = empty_model<T, Serializable::model>;

template <class T>
using my_model = empty_model<T, Serializable::Model, ReportError::Model>;
```

The last thing that we need is to change the concept to have a constructor that accepts the actual `shared_ptr`:

```
Serializable(shared_ptr<const Concept> x) : self_(move(x)) {}
```

So you could in principle now write a concrete class, `Foo`, and do something like:

```
auto f = make_shared<my_model<Foo>>(Foo{});
```

Remember (yeah, it's already getting hard...) that `my_model` will inherit from the nested model classes (suitably templated), which inherit from the base concepts. That means that `my_model<Foo>` is a grandson of `Serializable::Concept`, so `f` will implicitly convert so that you can do this:

```
Serializable s(f);
```

All this said: while Sean Parents talks are brilliant (yes its easy to recognize), this is a lot of work, complexity and boilerplate. In my experience, 99% of the time in real code, you are better just writing off the interface, and then writing a concrete type that directly inherits from them. I'd make sure that your specific problem really benefits from this before going down this rabbit hole.

Comment: That is one fancy way to do multiple inheritance, variadic classes in the template signature. Thanks a bunch, and realize now that the increased complexity has to be merited before replacing the existing inheritance system

Comment: I've tried extending this approach to work with vectors and classes that do not have a default constructor, but failed hopelessly. That strengthens the case all the more for just sticking with the default inheritance.

Comment: I've been watching Sean's presentations about this and agree with you that it's a bit of a rabbit hole.